# Codeception Sub Folders

Tags: php, testing, codeception

As I understand it, out of the box Codeception will put *all* tests in one of the folders it makes based on type such as unit, functional, or acceptance. With large projects, that can easily get out of hand though. I'm trying to figure out how to have a structure like this:

```
- functional
    - Module1
        - Applications
            - ApplicationType1Cept.php
            - ApplicationType2Cept.php
        - Accounts
            - AccountType1Cept.php
            - AccountType2Cept.php
```

When I do this:

```
codecept.phar generate:cept functional AccountType1Cept
```

It will put the new file in the root of the functional folder. I've tried doing something like:

```
codecept.phar generate:cept functional/Module1/Applications AccountType1Cept
```

But that does not work. I suspect it has something to do with **suites**, but not sure.

How can I get codeception to generate (and execute) tests in a more organized structure?

Answer (score 0):

I am working on something similar, but on Windows. 
Right now I have installed Codeception as global using Composer:

```
composer global require "codeception/codeception=2.0.*"
composer global require "codeception/specify=*"
composer global require "codeception/verify=*"
```

This allows me to switch to a specific folder like yours "/Module1/Applications/" and then issue the commands directly, e.g.:

a) set up the test directory:

```
codecept bootstrap
```

b) create the tests by:

```
codecept generate:cept functional AccountType1Cept
```

If you prefer, you can do it from the main directory, but you have first to tell Codeception the name, then use the "-c" option to indicate that you want to execute the command in the directory that follows, and then the target directory. In your case (using Linux) it would be:

```
codecept.phar generate:cept functional AccountType1Cept -c ~/Module1/Applications
```

but for me it's too much typing, it's easier to just switch to the target folder and issue all the commands there :-)

More information:
http://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage#Running-from-different-folders

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need.
What you need to do is something like this:

```
codecept.phar generate:cept functional "Application\ApplicationType1Cept"
codecept.phar generate:cept functional "Account\AccountType1Cept"
```

This creates the test files in the folders you want and namespaces them also.

Comment: in this case, you may get error: `Failed to inject dependencies in instance of 'Application\ApplicationType1Cept'. Class Application\AcceptanceTester does not exist`. Just add backward-slash to dependency, e.g.: tryToTest(\AcceptanceTester $I)

Answer (score 0):

I did this without any specific suite configuration (version 3.1.2). For example: if you make a directory structure like this:

- tests

  - unit

    - Services

      - SomethingServiceTest.php

`codecept.phar run unit` will find your test.

Comment: Things may be different now. My question was asked 5 years ago.

Comment: Yes, but if somebody (as I did) stuck into a similar problem then this answer can be helpful. Sadly codeception's docs does not give any advice how we manage lots of test files.